# Two way binding with the download of data in an array

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, data-binding

I want to program a two ways binding in angular so that when I choose something it can be displayed without me refreshing the page.
My code looks like this:

markup

```
<div *ngFor="let container of containers>
  <div class=task-list-plus *ngFor="let task of tasks">
    <mat-card [courseId]="courseID" [task]="task" [taskResult]="taskResults[task.id]"></mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts code

```
containers: Container[];
courseID: number;
tasks: Task[];
taskResults: Record<number, UserTaskResult>;

this.taskService.getAllContainer(this.courseID).subscribe((Container) => this.containers = Container);
```

the getAllContainer function downloads the data into the container. My question is how can I program it so that as soon as it is downloaded it is displayed directly without refreshment of the page.enter code here

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put another component in your card.
and use @Input() [Angular parent child component](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)